# SQL or sql/PHP for db setup script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not sure this is a good 'SO' style question, but don't know where else to ask.

I'm working on a small project, and I'm setting up the database with a certain amount of pre determined data.

This data needs a certain amount of 'pre treatment' to get the data into the DB and have the DB in a reasonable state (trying to attain 3rd normal form).

TLDR : What arguments could I use for keeping all this in pure SQL rather than using the added power that would come with PHP.

complete info:

There is one thing that is bothering me, I could do this work in either straight SQL (we are using MySQL in this instance), and I've developped a number of rather nice little scripts to extract, sort and clean things up. This is found to meet great approval from my colleagues.

I'm wondering in my own mind however if I would be better in some istance to be running some of the clean up via php, as it would make for code that was less 'verbose' ~ could easily be slipped into a loop in php for example.

I can think of a number of reasons why keeping the setup in pure SQL could be better. eg allowing for the DB moved to another machine, and prepared, without this other machine needing to have a php interpreter, or needing to be connected to a system that does.

But I'm struggling to think of any other good arguments, I'm sure the question will arise, and would like to be ready with the killer argument(s) when it does.

Thanks for your input.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say without knowing the details of the project, and who might be working on it later, and what their skills are. One thing to keep in mind would be the likelihood that you would change your database in the future. If so, then I would code everything in PHP, and let a framework handle turning that into proper SQL for you database.

If a change in programming language is more likely, though, then stick with SQL scripts. If you're going to run the script with a continuous integration engine, which is easier to implement, the SQL or PHP?

If you need some sort of version control for the SQL scripts, that's probably more easily done in PHP than straight SQL, but I've never tried the latter.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the migrating to another DB issue. Surely version control will work on any text base language, I hadn't thought about putting this script in version control.

Comment: Version control will work on any file. But, correctly written, you can version control whether your db scripts have run or not. This is easier from php than sql.

Comment: Using version control to determine if the script has run or not. Interesting thought, but what would be wrong with simple logging ?  Also these scripts are likely to run inside virtual machines, so will probably only run a few times, and then the machine will likely be chucked out to start with a fresh system. Thanks for making the effort to answer.

Comment: You could also just log things. Using php lets you take advantage of inheritance to make sure all the scripts follow some general steps, like writing to a log file when they are run.